# bi-interpretability and automorphism groups

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

Let $M$ and $N$ be two first order structures, say they are countable and $\aleph_0$-categorical. Then $M$ and $N$ are bi-interpretable if and only if their automorphism groups $Aut(M)$ and $Aut(N)$ are isomorphic as topological groups.

Is the same true in general? What if $M$ and $N$ are uncountably categorical.

Comment: I think you have confused "$\aleph_0$-categorical" with "isomorphic".
What is the topology of $Aut(M)$?

Comment: @nombre Topology on the automorphism group is as a subspace of $M^M$ with the product topology, where $M$ has the discrete topology. I still don't have a good idea what the question is asking, though.

Comment: The question is referring to the theorem of Ahlbrandt and Ziegler that two countable countably categorical structures $M$ and $N$ are *bi-interpretable* if and only if $\text{Aut}(M) \cong \text{Aut}(N)$ as topological groups. Bi-interpretable appears in the title but not the body of the question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, thanks. I indeed forgot to write they are bi-interpretable in the body.